# Bold marked region in org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way in `org-mode` to mark region (one or few words) and make them bold/italic?

Currently, if I want to turn `bar` into bold face, I have to move the point before the `b` add `*` and then navigate the point right after `r` and add another `*`. I want to be able to mark the whole word `bar`, hit something like `C-c C-f C-b` (did someone said AUCTeX?) and obtain `*bar*`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`org-emphasize` does what you need. It is bound to <kbd>C-c C-x C-f</kbd> and then you suppy either the marker (`*` or `_`) or the first letter of the corresponding HTML tag (e.g. `e` for `<em>`).

Documentation here: http://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-emphasize